# React-router-dom - No routes matching location '/' when Route has param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to figure out why passing a param using React-router-dom's Link and Route is not working correctly.
My routes are configured this way:

**App.tsx**

```
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/:id" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/search" element={<Search />} />
  </Routes>
```

**Home** renders data using a default initial ID, And I am using **Link** inside the **Search** component to send an id param to render data in **Home** using this different id, this way:

**Search.tsx**

```
<Link to={`../${idParam}`}>
  <li>
    Some Link
  </li>
</Link>
```

What I expect: when the URL points to '/', the default **Home** component should be rendered. When a param is added **Home** should receive this param and be rendered using the id sent.

However, currently **Home** will only be rendered when an id is provided as a param (for example: '/1234'). When navigating to **'/'**, React responds with **'No routes matched location "/"**'

Appreciate any help clarifying what's wrong with my set-up, thanks!

Comment: try this ```<Link to={`/${idParam}`}>```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now route matches exact path by default. Uptill v5 we could declare a parameter optional by using a question mark symbol(?). But unfortunately its no longer available in v6. Ref - [issues](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7285)
Now instead of optional parameter, you can declare children routes under a parent route. Use the code below in **App.tsx**

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/">
    <Route path=":id" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="" element={<Home />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/search" element={<Search />} />
</Routes>
```

Also change your code in **Search.tsx** to

```
<Link to={`/${idParam}`}>
  <li>
    Some Link
  </li>
</Link>
```